# How do I access list elements where list is defined inside map

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

...
var mapExp = [{"name":'Ram', "skill":['dart','SEO'] }]
...

How do I access skill 'dart' or 'SEO' ?

Comment: mapExp['skill'] to get the array, and after you can foreach into

Comment: mapExp['skill'][0] to get 'dart', mapExp['skill'][1] to get 'SEO' .....